# Transform 2 d hash into 1 d hash

Tags: ruby, hash, dictionary

With this Hash:

```
{ "blog_namespace" : { "key" : "blog_post_1234",
                       "notice" : "Read the new blog post!" } }
```

What's the quickest way to translate it into the Hash:

```
{ "blog_post_1234" : "Read the new blog post!" }
```

?

I always see people using clever combinations of `map` and `merge` etc, but can't quite get my head around a way to do this without nesting two loops together.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

These hashes appear to be JSON objects. If they are, use a [JSON parser](http://rubygems.org/gems/json) to transform them into ruby hashes.

```
hash = {"blog_namespace" => {"key" => "blog_post_1234",
                             "notice" => "Read the new blog post!"}}

Hash[hash.map {|k, v| [v["key"], v["notice"]] }]
# => {"blog_post_1234" => "Read the new blog post!"}
```

Comment: Too easy! I'd never seen that syntax for construction a Hash before (i.e. Hash[]).  It works! :)  I can remove my loops and feel more like a one-lining Ruby pro now :P

Comment: I just wrote the data structure in JSON format, as that's where the data is coming from, but I have converted it to a Hash using `ActiveSupport::JSON` from Rails.

Comment: slight variation using Facets: hash.mash { |k, v| [v["key"], v["notice"]] }

Answer (score 2):

This wasn't a valid Ruby hash. But given the assumptions that it is (or you'll parse it into one) and that the key will always be `"blog_namespace"`, you can do the following:

```
>> Hash[[h["blog_namespace"].values]] 
#=> {"blog_post_1234"=>"Read the new blog post!"}
```

Comment: Sorry, I should probably have clarified that there would be more than one entry in the Hash... blog_namespace was just one of many namespaces.  But thanks :) (The data is converted into a Ruby Hash from JSON).